# State history in Pytransitions

Tags: python, state-machine, pytransitions

I am using [Pytransitions](https://pypi.org/project/transitions/) and I have some state machine, for example

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions import EventData


class Matter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        transitions = [
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'solid', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'heat', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'gas'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'gas', 'dest': 'liquid'},
            {'trigger': 'cool', 'source': 'liquid', 'dest': 'solid'}
        ]
        self.machine = Machine(
                model=self,
                states=['solid', 'liquid', 'gas'],
                transitions=transitions,
                initial='solid',
                send_event=True
        )

    def on_enter_gas(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering gas from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_liquid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering liquid from {event.transition.source}")

    def on_enter_solid(self, event: EventData):
        print(f"entering solid from {event.transition.source}")
```

Is there some library-supported way to keep track of all the history of the states?

What I am manually doing now is on init:

```
after_state_change=lambda event: self._on_after_state_change(event)
```

and

```
def _on_after_state_change(self, event: EventData):
    to_state = event.transition.dest
    self._history_df.append({
        "start_index": self._index,
        "state": to_state
    }, ignore_index=True)
```

---

I was wondering if the library supported some **query-able** logging, meaning not just dumping events to a file, but also being able to keep them in a list for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions does not feature a built-in history. If you just want to track the previous states, [this](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/313#issuecomment-423899913) GitHub issue might be helpful:

> Since the stateful object with transitions is the model you can use the state property to track state changes:

```py
from transitions import Machine
import collections


# if you like your machine to act as a model, let Model inherit from Machine
class Model(object):

    def __init__(self, history_length):
        self.state_history = collections.deque(maxlen=history_length)

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.state_history[-1]

    @state.setter
    def state(self, value):
        self.state_history.append(value)


model = Model(3)
machine = Machine(model, states=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], initial='A')
print(model.state)  # >>> A

model.to_B()
model.to_C()
model.to_A()
model.to_D()

print("->".join(model.state_history))  # >>> C->A->D
```

This only works with `model_attribute='state'` (default value). In case you altered the name of the 'stateful' model field, you need to adjust the above mentioned properties accordingly.

If you are interested in all `EventData`, your approach seems to be the go to solution. You can omit the lambda though. `after_state_change=self._on_after_state_change` or `after_state_change='_on_after_state_change'` (if the method is part of the model) should be enough.

The above mentioned `dequeue` (or `queue.Queue`) is 'queryable' in a way that you can use filters or list comprehensions with it. If you need something more sophisticated, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) (which you probably already use considering your history name) or [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) might be more suitable.